# Java HashSet seems to contain duplicate values

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a unit test that fails about 1 out of 30 times, I don't understand why. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
@Test
void size() {
    int totalIndexes = 10;
    Set<Integer> usedIndexes = new HashSet<>();
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    Stream.generate(() -> index.getAndIncrement() % totalIndexes).parallel().limit(1000).forEach(i -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        usedIndexes.add(i);
    });
    if (usedIndexes.size() > totalIndexes) {
        // Should be impossible?
        System.out.println(usedIndexes.stream().map(i -> String.format("%s %d", i, i.hashCode()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" | ")));
        System.out.println("Total: " + usedIndexes.size());
    }
    assertTrue(usedIndexes.size() <= totalIndexes);
}
```

The sleep is there just to make sure several threads are used, as it seems to be connected to the problem (not sure). Without it, the problem occurred after about 30K runs.

As you can see I added prints for the bad case and got some example outputs such as:

```
0 0 | 1 1 | 2 2 | 3 3 | 4 4 | 5 5 | 6 6 | 7 7 | 8 8 | 9 9
Total: 26

8 8 | 0 0 | 9 9 | 1 1 | 2 2 | 3 3 | 4 4 | 5 5 | 6 6 | 7 7 | 4 4 | 5 5 | 6 6 | 7 7
Total: 16
```

Breakpoint screenshot:

[image]

Furthermore, not trusting my years writing Java I decided to ask ChatGPT about it:

Me:

> Consider this test: Can usedIndexes ever be bigger than 10 objects? How? [code above]

Chat:

> The value of usedIndexes should always be less than or equal to
> totalIndexes because the stream is generating integers between 0 and
> totalIndexes - 1 (inclusive) by using the modulo operator % and the
> getAndIncrement() method on the AtomicInteger object index. The stream
> is then limited to 1000 elements, so it will not generate more than
> 1000 integers. Since the usedIndexes set only stores unique integers,
> its size should never be greater than totalIndexes.
>
> It is possible that usedIndexes can be equal to totalIndexes if every
> number generated is unique and it is also possible that usedIndexes
> can be smaller than totalIndexes if some of the generated numbers are
> same. This is because, the HashSet only stores unique elements and the
> size of the set will be the number of unique elements.

I must be missing something simple here. Using latest IntelliJ, Java 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) does not support concurrent access. Use [`ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet()) instead.

From `HashSet`'s docs:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally.

As you are adding elements from within a terminal operation of a *parallel* stream, you are breaking `HashSet`'s contract, thus experiencing the inconsistent results you have described.

Comment: A(nother) great example of why using streams, especially for less experienced programmers, isn't always a great choice. They might seem "sexy" to some, but they often lead to less readable code or subtle bugs like this one.

Comment: Thnx @fps, I think I got used to getting `ConcurrentModificationException` in such cases, didn't know not all collections throw it.

Comment: @E-Riz Note that this is a simplified version of a test that actually used an executor service. I even added a sleep (bad practice obviously) to make the problem worse.
If anything it's an example of how ChatGPT can miss something simple just like us ;)

Comment: @EugeneMarin `ConcurrentModificationException` is something different. It doesn't have anything to do with accessing a collection from different threads. That exception is thrown when you *structurally* modify the collection by either adding or removing elements, while you are iterating it. And this can happen in a single-threaded environment